# How to enable links within 'return false' div.click

Tags: javascript

I have been playing with the modal here, and so far I've learned a good bit, but still need your help, guys. 
I didn't want the modal to close when you clicked it randomly (eg. scroll, etc.), so the *return false* event was added on click. But how would you go about allowing links inside *(.modal)* to still work?

```
$('#modal-container').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('out');
        $('body').removeClass('modal-active');
});

$('#close-btn').click(function(){
        $('#modal-container').click();
});

$('.modal').click(function(e){
        return false;
});
```

Thanks again for your help! ^_^

Comment: Don't know the structure of your document..., but [this](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) may help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should check which element is clicked. if not only anchor return false.

```
$('.modal').click(function(e) {
    if (!($(e.target).is('a')))
    {
      return false;
    }           
});
```

Comment: Beautiful! It works, and helps me understand that bit more :D Thanks a village!